# Are $\bigcap\{Y\in\wp(S):X\subseteq Y\}$ and $X$ sets equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$S$ is a set, $\wp(S)$ is the power set of $S$.

$\forall X\subseteq S$, are $\bigcap\{Y\in\wp(S):X\subseteq Y\}$ and $X$ sets equal?

I think that since $X$ is a subset of $S$ and $Y$ satisfies the condition $X\subseteq Y$, so $X$ must exist in $\{Y\in\wp(S):X\subseteq Y\}$, and $X$ is the set with the least elements, so $\bigcap\{Y\in\wp(S):X\subseteq Y\}$ = $X$.

Is my understanding correct? If it is wrong, could you cite a counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the set $\bigcap\{Y\in\wp(S):X\subseteq Y\}$ ?

Comment: Yes. They are equal. The argument for "least elements" is not accurate, though. The inclusion $\subseteq$ is trivial, since $X$ is in that collection as you point out; in the other direction pick $x\in X$, and verify that it is in every member of the collection. Fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct proof:

- As $X$ is contained in each $Y$, it is trivial that $X$ is contained in their intersection.
- Conversely, split the intersection in two:
  $$\bigcap_{X\subseteq Y\strut}Y=X\cap\Bigl(\bigcap_{X\varsubsetneq Y\strut}Y\Bigr)$$
  is contained in $X$, as any intersection of $X$ with another set.

Comment: Or, don't split the intersection into two; just note that $X\subseteq X$, so $X$ belongs to the collection we're intersecting, and therefore the intersection is a subset of $X$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: That's right. It used this formulation to make it clearer to beginners.